# been trying to launch Intelli J IDEA on my computer but I keep getting a failure to create JVM path message

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-toolbox, jetbrains-hub

> Failed to create JVM.JVM path:C:\Users\admin
> pc\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition
> 2019.2.3\jbr\

I've tried defining a JAVA_HOME variable in the environment variables under the system settings,but the same error keeps occurring,pls is there any other solution

Comment: Does it help if you delete the custom .vmoptions file located in the config directory? See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544869 and https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519 .

Comment: I will try doing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you installed JDK, and reinstall IntelliJ.

Comment: I just tried doing this again and it worked!. thanks